# php connection to mysql db fails after ajax call

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a function that connects to Mysql DB that works great in a "normal" call, but fails to connect in response to ajax call.

The php code:

```
  // return data to ShowDdl()
  function getDDLdata($tablename) {

  global $db;
  $data = '';

  $name = ($tablename == 'sapak' || $tablename == 'cupon' ? 'Name' : 'Hebrewname');   
  ////****** $db IS NOT RECOGNIZED WHEN CALLING ShowDdl() FROM AJAX
  ////****** BUT WORKS GREAT IN NORMAL CALLS
  $query = $db->select("SELECT `id` , `".$name."` AS name FROM `".$tablename."` ORDER BY    `id` ASC");

  for($i=0;$result = $db->get_row($query, 'MYSQL_ASSOC');$i++){
      $data[$i] = $result;
  }

  return $data; // id, name
}

// echo ddl with current data from requested table 
   function ShowDdl($tablename, $sapakid = null) {
      $possibletables = array (
           'category', 'subcategory', 'brand', 'sapak', 'cupon'
     );

   $ddlname = '';

// find the correct name for the ddl    
for ($i = 0; $i<count($possibletables); $i++) {    

    if ($possibletables[$i] == $tablename) {            
        // only cupon ddl should have different id and name
        if ($tablename == 'cupon') {
            $ddlname = 'sapak-'.$sapakid .'-cupon';
        }
        else {
            $ddlname = 'product-' . $tablename;
        }

        continue;
    }        
}

echo '<select multiple id="'.$ddlname.'" name="'.$ddlname.'[]">';

$data = getDDLdata($tablename);    

foreach ($data as $vn ) {

    if ($vn['id'] != null) {
        echo '                 
             <option value="'.$vn['id'].'"> '.$vn['name'].' </option>
             ';
    }
}    
echo '</select>';
```

}

It works great when called from 'normal' php.

The ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'moudels/product/generic_offer.php',
        data: 'sid=' + sid + '&name=' + name,                                        
        success: function (data) {
            $('<div id='+ sid + '> </div>').appendTo('#genericofferdiv');
            // append the response to the new div
            $("#"+sid).html(data);
        }
    });
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function select() on a non-object
```

I'm sure it it because the ajax call, maybe it can't load the global $db var correctly. Any ideas how I solve this?

Thank you very much

*Note: I know that I should use mysqli, but the whole project is build with this and I can't change it

Comment: Where is `$db` supposed to come from here...?

Comment: Did you include $db at the top of the file?

Comment: it is a global var in all the project.

Comment: The error your getting is typically because the database variable is not available

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: But why is it not available? When calling the php file from another php file, $db is available, but when calling it from the ajax, it is not. Is this simply how ajax works?

Comment: Go type in the URL `moudels/product/generic_offer.php?sid=...&name=...` into your browser's address bar. That's all an AJAX request does, basically. Should your `$db` variable exist there? Does this explain why it does not?

Comment: Where do you get a `MySQL` object from? You say you don't use `MySQLi`, MySQL queries should look like this http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php. :)

Comment: Update your question with more of your code

Comment: @dollarvar I use a class for the mysql querys. This php function works great in 4 other different 'normal' php calls. The problem is probably that as you guys said, the $db var doesn't exist when called from ajax. I'll have to find out how to make it 'known'.

Comment: @user1223457 Yeah, put the `class` up! This is definitely a PHP error, it does not care where the `GET` comes from. ;)

Comment: posted all the php code

Comment: try including the file that contains your $db variable at the top

Comment: your global $db is being created in index.php and then it dies when index.php finishes loading, then ajax is calling the other script when $db is already dead so even if it is global you should recreate it.

Comment: you also might need to pass it the $db variable in the function I have never used the global variable like that before but if you don't have the file loaded where you first create that variable I don't believe you will have access to it

Answer (score 0):

When you call / include this file from within your php project, you probably defined somewhere the global variable $db and can access it in this file, too.

But if you call this from you website, all the php has run through and no global variable exist anymore...
-> So you have to include f.e. the config.php where you defined your $db variable again!

config.php:

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PW, DB_DB);
```

yourFile.php

```
require_once('./config.php');
```